# Careless packing

Tags: combinatorial-geometry, packing-and-covering

The sequence $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2\cdot 2}, \frac{1}{3\cdot 4}, \frac{1}{4\cdot 6}, \frac{1}{5\cdot 8}, \frac{1}{6\cdot 10},\ldots$ has a curious property, as follows:

a) the series with these terms sums to 1;

b) no process of sequentially packing open intervals with these lengths into the unit interval $[0,1]$ can ever come to an impasse.

Many other sequences also enjoy this property.

Question: has this type of phenomena ever appeared in the literature?

In particular I wonder about possible decompositions (up to a set of measure zero)
of, say, the unit square (or unit sphere) into open sets which enjoy the corresponding property.

Comment: For more than one dimension, I imagine that it is unlikely that any exist.  A (relatively) old MathOverflow question of Segerman asks to pack circles of total area 1/2 into a circle of area 1, and that has not been fully resolved.  Gerhard "Still Am Working On It" Paseman, 2012.03.05

Comment: @G "" P:  I'm having trouble seeing the precise connection between 
the two questions.  Segerman asks about an *arbitrary* collection of *circles* except for a bound on total area; I ask about a carefully contrived ordered collection of open sets.

Comment: There may be no precise connection.  However, there seems to be difficulty in doing a loose packing even if you get to choose an order in which to pack, and are given a sequence ahead of time, and you have room to spare.  That his problem is difficult suggests to me that the two dimensional version of your problem is even more so.
Gerhard "It's How I See Things" Paseman, 2012.03.05

Comment: I did not know such a sequence exists! Cool! The reason (b) holds is the divergence of the harmonic series, so I do not think there is a generalization to squares in 2d, say. The case of 1xL rectangles of course follows trivially from the 1d case.

Comment: John Shier, a retired physicist turned artist, has an interest in sequences of this type for use in computer-generated abstract art.  He has a nice write-up at http://john-art.com/stat_geom_described_v3.pdf (and you can get to more by backing up the url).

Comment: Thanks Barry Cipra for the pointer to John Shier.
I had thought to point out that Shier merely asks for no impasse with probability 1.  Now it occurs to me that that implies no possibility of any impasse!  Indeed if one can contrive an impasse after the packing of N-1 items, any sufficiently small deformation of that configurations will also block the Nth item. That gives at least a small positive probability for failing when placing items at random.

Comment: It is easy to characterize all sequences $a_1,a_2,\dots$ with this property: A necessary and sufficient condition is that $(k+1)a_{k+1}\leq 1−\sum_{j=1}^ka_j$ for all $k$. The above sequence
$1/2,1/4,\dots$ is thus the optimal sequence starting with $1/2$. 

Comment: Sorry for the naive question, but, can you please explain what do you mean by "come to an impasse"? What happens if you take the following sequence: 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 0, ...?

Comment: As a (very belated) example: If I place the first two intervals at $[0.1, 0.6]$ and $[0.7, 0.95]$, then there is now nowhere I can place the third interval.   While there's enough space overall for it $(0.25)$, the space is split up into pieces of size smaller than $0.125$.

Comment: >While there's enough space overall for it (0.25), the space is split up into pieces of size smaller than 0.125....
The third term of the sequence is 1/12, not 1/8.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a rigorous justification of Johan Wästlund's intuition. Namely, I will show that if we tile a round ball $B$ of area $\pi\zeta(\alpha)$ by round balls of area $\pi/n^\alpha$ for some $1<\alpha<1.1716$, then we never get stuck provided we have placed enough balls already.

For later use note that the radius of $n$'th ball is $n^{-\alpha/2}$.
Suppose we have placed the first $N-1$ balls. Let $U$ be the union of them, and let $U'$ be the complement of $B$. We can place $N$'th ball iff the $N^{-\alpha/2}$-neighborhood of $U\cup U'$ does not contain all of $B$. We can bound the area of the neighborhood of $U$ by $$\sum_{n < N} \pi(n^{-\alpha/2}+N^{-\alpha/2})^2=\sum_{n < N} \pi(n^{-\alpha}+2n^{-\alpha/2}N^{-\alpha/2}+N^{-\alpha})=\pi(\Sigma_1+\Sigma_2+\Sigma_3).$$ We have $\Sigma_1\approx \zeta(\alpha)-\frac{N^{1-\alpha}}{\alpha-1}$, $\Sigma_2\approx 2N^{-\alpha/2} \frac{N^{1-\alpha/2}}{1-\alpha/2}=\frac{2}{1-\alpha/2}N^{1-\alpha}$ and $\Sigma_3\approx N^{1-\alpha}$. The area of the neighborhood of $U'$ is less than $2\pi\zeta(\alpha)^{1/2}N^{-\alpha/2}=o(N^{1-\alpha})$. The result follows since $$\frac{1}{\alpha-1}-\frac{2}{1-\alpha/2}-1$$ is positive for $\alpha<4-2\sqrt{2}=1.17157\ldots$.

*Edit*: Actually, the argument works for any centrally symmetric convex shapes. The only thing I used about balls is that the Minkowski sum of a ball and a ball is a ball of the correct size.

*Edit 2*: It is clear that if one wants a stronger conclusion that one never gets stuck, then one needs to make explicit errors in the asymptotic estimates above. Then one can either decrease $\alpha$ to subsume those errors, or to consider the balls of area $\pi m^{-\alpha},\pi(m+1)^{-\alpha},\dotsc$ in a ball of total area $\pi\sum_{n\geq m} n^{-\alpha}$ to reduce the errors. This mirrors the suggestion of John Shier in the write-up linked  above.

Comment: Doesn't the Nth neighborhood depend on 2N rather than on N?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.03.06

Comment: No, think of the centers of the balls. $r$-neighborhood of a set $U$ is the set of all the points $p$ such that the ball centered at $p$ intersects $U$.

Comment: Are you accounting for the boundary of the packed region?  You won't be able to squeeze a ball on the outer edge if the others are placed too near the edge.  Not that I am against the proof, I am just concerned that the error is larger than you think. Gerhard "Still Worried About The Calculation" Paseman, 2012.03.06

Comment: So one should look now to raise that upper bound 1.1716, right?
Some sort of sieve should improve the area estimate.

Comment: Great! But as Gerhard points out, there is also a problem near the boundary of the box. There is an unavailable region of area at most $2\pi\zeta(\alpha)^{1/2}N^{-\alpha/2}$. The estimate becomes a little messier, but it's clear it will work for all $N$ if $\alpha$ is small.

Comment: I still think that the proper satement should be that the Nth ball can be placed iff the neighborhood of the union does not contain all of the ball B minus a thin patch.  Boris's final quantity in $\alpha$ should actually be greater than $2\pi\sqrt{\zeta(\alpha)}N^{-1 + \alpha/2}$, which may be true for the stated $\alpha$ but I would like to see it.  Gerhard "Those Troublesome Unsightly Dirty Rings" Paseman, 2012.03.06 

Comment: Ummm, yeah.  What Johan said.  Right.  Gerhard "Minutes Late And Nickels Short" Paseman, 2012.03.06

Comment: @Gerhard and @Johan: Thanks, I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 11):

My guess is that such sets exist in all dimensions. Here's a partial answer that explains why. Let's consider tilings of a rectangular box of area $\zeta(\alpha)$ by axis-parallel rectangular tiles of areas $1/n^\alpha$ for some $\alpha>1$. We allow the tiles to be squeezed and stretched by axis-parallel linear transformations as long as the area is preserved. Suppose that we have carelessly placed the first $N$ tiles. Then the remaining space can be divided into $3N+1$ rectangular sub-boxes. Since the next tile has area roughly $(\alpha-1)/N$ times the remaining space, we can fit the next tile into the largest sub-box provided $\alpha<4/3$.

If we don't permit squeezing and stretching, we might get into trouble because all sub-boxes that are large enough are too oblong. But it seems that if $\alpha$ is small enough and we subdivide in some reasonable way (say to minimize the total perimeter of the sub-boxes), then this should not happen.

Comment: For those for whom the appearance of $3N+1$ is not immediately obvious: Think of a line that sweeps the box from top to bottom. Above the line there are partially completed rectangles that rectangulate the free area above the line. Each time the sweep line meets a placed rectangle R, any partially completed rectangle is declared completed, and the vertical sides of R are two vertical lines that define three new rectangles to be completed. This is in essence a "line sweep algorithm" (see wikipedia) applied to rectangulation of the box minus rectangles.